# Why my hot water goes out in less than 2 mins?

Tags: water-heater, faucet, hot-water

All the water outlets in my condo can only supply hot water for at most 2 mins and then I am left with cold water. I changed my gas water heater 2 days ago, but the problem continues. I was desperate when I thought the problem was finally resolved but was left with cold water again during a shower. Do anybody happen to know what is going on here ? Thank you a lot.

Comment: We are going to need more information. You said "water heater" and you also said you changed it. What model & size/type was it before, and what model/size and type is it now? Was it installed by a professional? How many handles do the faucets in your condo have? (one or two). What temperature are you setting the heater to? is it direct vent or vented out a stack? If you can see the flame, what color is it? Is there any water in the apartment that runs constantly? Where is this water heater located? Is it in a climate controlled space (even just minorly)?

Comment: Also, it it a tank or on-demand?

Comment: If a tank type was the water supply plumbed to the inlet (there is a difference and being backwards can cause this).

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the dip tubes on hot water heater.
2. Isolate the hot water heater to make sure the heater was running properly.
3. Turn off the radiant heat systems and bypass them with the built-in valves.
4. Open up each shower fixture and close off the water valves to take those out of the equation. 
   If the hot water still run cold do next:
5. Remove the recirculating pump and check the system.
6. Remove the check valves beginning with the one near the recirculating pump and discover the broken valve. If this still didn't work, they would've kept going to check every check valve in the system(three total).

Maybe it helps

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! While this may be a good set of troubleshooting steps in some situations, the OP never mentioned radiant heat systems or a recirculating pump, so I'm not sure how applicable most of this advice is.